# jQuery if multiple objects equal same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, equals

I have multple objects. Before submitting a form, I want to check to be sure all of the object values are "ok".

```
$("#sub_button").click(function() {
    if (myObj.login_id && myObj.email == "ok")  {
        alert("This would submit the form. login ID obj is: "+myObj.login_id+" and email email obj is: "+myObj.email);
    } else {
        alert("the form is bad!");
    }
});
```

I've tried it with two == and three ===, it still isn't working. The `myObj.login_id` or `myObj.email` could equal ANYTHING and it still pops up the "This would submit the form" alert, and shows in the alert box that the value(s) is NOT "ok".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
("#sub_button").click(function() {

    if (myObj.login_id === "ok" && myObj.email === "ok")  {

        alert("This would submit the form. login ID obj is: "+myObj.login_id+" and email email obj is: "+myObj.email);
else {

        alert("the form is bad!");
```

In your code you just check that `myObj.login_id` resolves to true (which happens everytime `myObj.login_id` value is not in this list)

- false
- null
- undefined
- The empty string ''
- The number 0
- The number NaN (yep, 'Not a Number' is a number, it is a special number)

Comment: I can't believe I didnt catch that. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This isn't comparing what you think it's comparing. When you read this aloud, it sounds right: "if login ID and email are equal to OK", but that's not how the `&&` works. You want:

```
if (myObj.login_id == "ok" && myObj.email == "ok") {
   ....
}
```

The code you did write actually says "if login ID is anything at all, and if email is "ok" ".

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#sub_button").click(function() {
    if (myObj.login_id == "ok" && myObj.email == "ok")  {
        alert("This would submit the form. login ID obj is: "+myObj.login_id+" and email email obj is: "+myObj.email);
    } else {
        alert("the form is bad!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`(myObj.login_id && myObj.email == "ok")` will evaluate to true if `myObj.email == "ok"` and `myObj.login_id` has a non-zero value. You're not evaluating the contents of `login_id` to anything, so it'll be handled as a boolean and converted to such according to the contents.

You should change it to `(myObj.login_id == "ok" && myObj.email == "ok")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#sub_button").click(function() {

    if (myObj.login_id == "ok" && myObj.email == "ok")  {

        alert("This would submit the form. login ID obj is: "+myObj.login_id+" and email email obj is: "+myObj.email);

    } else {

        alert("the form is bad!");
```